# facebook publish_actions - default visibility to friends of friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use publish_actions scope to post on user's behalf like so:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&state=%s&scope=publish_actions
```

This shows the user a dialog where the default visibility level is set to 'Friends'. For example see the little dropdown at the bottom left of the screenshot shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/#logindialog)

Is it possible to have this visibility level to be set to 'Friends of Friends' by default?

Comment: No, this isn't allowed.

Comment: Instead of visibility here, you can set the visibility of the post instead. Try doing that

Comment: @Anvesh, Not sure how I can do that assuming the user allows only Friend level permission here.

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: See ny answer. It's IMHO not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set the visibility programatically during the Login Permission Dialog.

What you can theoratically do is setting the privacy level while publishing a post for a user (if you have the `publish_actions` permission):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed#publish

This will **NOT** overwrite the standard setting the user selected privacy level during login. So, if I chose "Friends", then the app will not be able to post to friends of friends.

Example:

```
POST /v2.2/me/feed
```

Raw Body:

```
message=Test+message&privacy={"value":"FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS"}
```

results in

```
{
    "id": "{post_id}"
}
```

Check:

```
/{post_id}?fields=id,message,privacy
```

results in

```
{
  "id": "{post_id}", 
  "message": "Test message", 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Your friends", 
    "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
    "friends": "", 
    "networks": "", 
    "allow": "", 
    "deny": ""
  }, 
  "created_time": "2015-01-26T14:49:39+0000"
}
```

Comment: detailed and good answer, the very first sentence would have been good enough (and definitely correct) already :)